# Source for the Beit Yosef's צ

Tags: sources-mekorot, safrus, aleph-bet-letters

In most forms of k'tav stam (Sephardi, Ari, Jeckisch, et c.) the righthand yud of the letter צ is reversed (see fig. 1). On the other hand, the Beit Yosef's צ uses a regular י shape in the righthand yud (fig. 2).

Why is there a discrepancy and what are the sources for both forms of yudin?

Fig. 1
[image: Jeckisch Tzade]

Fig. 2
[image: Beit Yosef Tzade]

Comment: Can you at least point to *your* sources for these "most" and "B"Y" examples?

Comment: _Jeckisch_? Seriously? This is a Chasidishe (Ari z"l) thing, I thought.

Comment: The BY one has a Yud/Vav head. Every STaM head is either a Yud/Vav head or a Zayin head. Very simple. Look at the heads on the Shin, for instance. Would it seem natural to write them backwards?

Comment: @DannySchoemann, no, see R' Hamburger's Shorshei Minhag Ashkenaz, as well as his madrich, which discuss ksav sta"m. This was also the p'sak I received from him regarding how I should write sta"m when I get kabbalah as a sofer.

Comment: the question is starting the wrong way. The Beis Yosef, M"B, Ceses HaSofer, Shulchan Aruch HaRav (before quoting the Ari), etc are all like Fig 2. The Ari Zal says to make like Fig 1. The question should be what's the makor for the Ari...